# PRAW induced SSL error when compiling Python script using py2exe

Tags: python, ssl, python-requests, py2exe, praw

Python 2.7.11

Requests 2.9.1

Praw 3.4.0

I have a python script that uses PRAW (reddit API wrapper), I'm attempting to compile it into an .exe using py2exe.

Here is the current error that occurs when the .exe is run:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "MYSCRIPTNAME.py", line 263, in <module>
  File "<decorator-gen-51>", line 2, in login
  File "praw\decorators.pyc", line 78, in wrap
  File "praw\__init__.pyc", line 1455, in login
  File "<decorator-gen-8>", line 2, in request_json
  File "praw\decorators.pyc", line 116, in raise_api_exceptions
  File "praw\__init__.pyc", line 620, in request_json
  File "praw\__init__.pyc", line 451, in _request
  File "praw\__init__.pyc", line 432, in handle_redirect
  File "praw\handlers.pyc", line 146, in wrapped
  File "praw\handlers.pyc", line 56, in wrapped
  File "praw\handlers.pyc", line 102, in request
  File "requests\sessions.pyc", line 576, in send
  File "requests\adapters.pyc", line 447, in send
requests.exceptions.SSLError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Line 263 is `r.login(user,pw)` (`r` is `r = praw.Reddit(userAgent)`)

Searching for other SSL issues on here and other places discussed adding cacert.pem.  I tried this without resolution.